# Network change Connectivity receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have implemented `broadcastReciever` in my code as follows for dynamically getting toast when internet is disconnected:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="<MY PACKAGE>">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".network.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginPage"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".network.ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
    ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
}
}
```

**BaseActivity.java**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private void checkConnection() {
    boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
    showSnack(isConnected);
}

public void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
    String message;
    int color;
    if (isConnected) {
        message = "Good! Connected to Internet";
        color = Color.WHITE;
    } else {
        message = "Sorry! Not connected to internet";
        color = Color.RED;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    showSnack(isConnected);
}
}
```

**LoginPage.java**

```
public class LoginPage extends BaseActivity {

Button btnSignin, btnSignup;
EditText etUserEmail, etUserPassword;
ImageView ivViewPassword;
private int mStatusCode;
Boolean flagLogin, flagPass = true;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
ProgressBar pbLoading;
RelativeLayout loadingView, rootlayout_loginPage;
Boolean success = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    init();
    testdata();
    ivViewPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (flagPass) {
                ivViewPassword.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_hide_password);
                etUserPassword.setTransformationMethod(null);
                flagPass = false;
            } else {
                ivViewPassword.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_show_password);
                etUserPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
                flagPass = true;
            }
        }
    });

    btnSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flagLogin = validateDetails();
            if (flagLogin) {
                etUserEmail.setError(null);
                etUserPassword.setError(null);
                loadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pbLoading.setIndeterminate(true);
                pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registration.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void testdata() {
    etUserEmail.setText("mncc@example.com");
    etUserPassword.setText("1234");
}

private void init() {
    btnSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignin);
    etUserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserEmail);
    etUserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserPassword);
    ivViewPassword = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivViewPassword);
    loadingView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingView);
    pbLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);
    btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignup);
    rootlayout_loginPage = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout_loginPage);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    showSnack(isConnected);
}

private boolean validateDetails() {
    if (etUserEmail.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        etUserEmail.setError("Email-ID can't be blank!");
        etUserEmail.setFocusable(true);
        return false;
    } else if (!Utils.isValidEmail(etUserEmail.getText().toString())) {
        etUserEmail.setError("Invalid Email-ID!");
        etUserEmail.setFocusable(true);
        return false;
    } else if (etUserPassword.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        etUserPassword.setError("Password can't be blank!");
        etUserPassword.setFocusable(true);
        return false;
    } /*else if (etUserPassword.getText().toString().length() < 8 || etUserPassword.getText().toString().length() > 16) {
        etUserPassword.setError("Password must be between 8-16 characters!");
        etUserPassword.setFocusable(true);
        return false;
    }*/ else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When i run the application on my android version oreo phone, it does not work ie it does not show any toast when i toggle network or wifi state. I am unable to figure out what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 1):

Apps targeting Android 7.0 and higher must register the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION dynamic Broadcast Receiver in an activity, **not** in the Manifest file. For example:

```
private ConnectivityReceiver connectivityReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connectivityReceiver= new ConnectivityReceiver();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    registerReceiver(connectivityReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(connectivityReceiver);
}
```